# Defer loading of js how?

Tags: javascript, html, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have the following js script referenced on the bottom of the page:

```
<script src="http://example.com/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Google PageSpeed suggestion is to defer the loading of this js. I don't quite understand how to do that or the repercussions. Can someone please explain?

Comment: Who cares what pageSpeed says, the important question is ***can*** the script be deferred, or in other words, is it something unimportant that won't matter if it's loaded after everything else is loaded.

Comment: It's possible doing so would be more effort than it's worth - `defer` is only compatible with newer browsers, and I think only helps if the script is declared in the `<head>`. However, if it *is* moved and the browser doesn't know `defer`, then it will mess up execution by running too early.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the attribute `defer` to the `<script>` tag should do it. E.g.:

```
<script src="http://example.com/test.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

The idea is that the script in the file is executed only after the whole page has finished loading, as opposed to the standard way when the script is executed as soon as the browser parses the `<script>` tag (which may delay rendering of the code after the `<script>` tag.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` attribute

```
<script src="http://example.com/test.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

Note:

The async attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: I like this option better. any downsides?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you'd want to do: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-async

> `<script async src="siteScript.js" onload="myInit()"></script>`

or

> `<script defer src="siteScript.js" onload="myInit()"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

None of those methods are really guaranteed to be executed. Check this great article on how to make sure that external javascript executions are really deffered.
[feedthebot deffer execute javascript](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html)

written by Patrick Sexton

Answer (score 0):

**async** might not be good option when there are dependencies from one js to another js. For eg . file1.js depends on file2.js , and file1.js loads first, starts executes but fails and throws an error due to some dependency in file2.js which is not loaded yet.