# Efficient way to defer js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I intend to call a js, which will not use anything when loading the page. Therefore, I need to call this js only when the entire page has been loaded, so as not to delay anything or load the screen for the user.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" defer=defer src="function.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function downloadJSAtOnload() {
                var element = document.createElement("script");
                element.src = "function.js";
                document.body.appendChild(element);
            }       
            if (window.addEventListener)
                window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
            else if (window.attachEvent)
                window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
            else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
    </script> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

My question is: in the above ways, which one would be more efficient? I need to decrease the loading time of my page and with that I want to "postpone" everything that is not necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defer loading of js how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079682/defer-loading-of-js-how)

Answer (score 1):

The “defer” keyword postpones loading of scripts until the DOMContentLoaded event is fired.

From the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event):

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been
> completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images,
> and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect
> a fully-loaded page).

This means that version 1 (defer) will possibly start loading the scripts earlier than version 2, while still keeping the loading efficient.